# Qt QProcess sudo BASH PASSWORD

Tags: qt, bash, qprocess

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте. Я тут взялся написать небольшую программку QtDeployer, ориентированную на Linux. Суть в том что там щелкаешь мышью, выбираешь release-файл, а она сама собирает ваше приложение, так что вам не надо печатать в терминале многабукав. По сути, это просто GUI для linuxdeployqt. И вот, базовый функционал, кажется, готов, но... Хочется добавить кнопку установки linuxdeployqt в /usr/bin, но тут возникают сложности с паролем. Конечно, можно реализовать инсталлер через BASH скрипт, где пользователь введет его сам, но, все же, хочется узнать, как скормить пароль в QProcess, чтобы реализовать запрос пароля именно через программу. По сути, тут вопрос упирается в синтаксис BASH. Как это сделать, чтобы команду можно было без проблем запихать в QProcess? Мне конкретно нужно чтобы было выполнено что-то типа

sudo cp linuxdeployqt.AppImage /usr/local/bin/linuxdeployqt

Еще добавлю кое-что. Вот, у меня версия 5.12.2 и такой код:

```
     QProcess *console=new QProcess();
     QString command;
     command = "echo MyPassword|sudo touch 1";
     console->startDetached(command);
```

И он почему-то не работает.

```
     QProcess process; 
     QString command = "echo MyPassword|sudo touch 1";    
     process.start(command);
```

Тоже не работает. Вывод приложения такой:

```
     QProcess: Destroyed while process ("echo") is still running.
```

Comment: QProcess process; process.start("echo your_password | sudo cp linuxdeployqt.AppImage /usr/bin/linuxdeployqt");

Comment: К сожалению, в моем случае это не работает.

Comment: А если так попробовать (через задание аргументов): `process.setProgram('echo');
process.setArguments(QStringList() << "MyPassword" << "|sudo" << "touch" << "1");
process.start();`

Answer (score 3):

Надо было посмотреть на что жалуется. В отличие от винды, в линуксе все команды должны чем то обрабатываться. Вам надо примерно такое:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    QProcess* p = new QProcess();
    connect(p,&QProcess::readyReadStandardError,this,&MainWindow::slot_readyRead);
    connect(p,&QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput,this,&MainWindow::slot_readyRead);
    connect(p,static_cast<void (QProcess::*)(int)>(&QProcess::finished),this,&MainWindow::slot_finished);
    QString password = QInputDialog::getText(this,"Hello", "Insert your password", QLineEdit::Password);
    p->start("sh", QStringList() << "-c" << QString("echo %1 | sudo -S %2").arg(password).arg(ui->lineEdit->text()));
}

void MainWindow::slot_finished(int exitCode)
{
    ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(QString("Process exited with code %1").arg(exitCode));
    qobject_cast<QProcess*>(sender())->deleteLater();
}

void MainWindow::slot_readyRead()
{
    QByteArray output = qobject_cast<QProcess*>(sender())->readAllStandardError();
    if(!output.isEmpty())
        ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(QString("\nERROR: %1\n").arg(QString::fromUtf8(output)));
    output = qobject_cast<QProcess*>(sender())->readAllStandardOutput();
        if(!output.isEmpty())
            ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(QString::fromUtf8(output));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за пример! ) Вот это сработало:  QProcess* p = new QProcess(); QString password = "MyPassword";      p->start("sh", QStringList() << "-c" << QString("echo %1 | sudo -S touch 1").arg(password));

Comment: Что-то рано я обрадовался. Не сразу заметил, в чем подвох. Все работает только когда запущено непосредственно из QtCreator или из терминала командой типа "./myProgram", а вот если из ярлыка *.desktop, тогда нефига, причем, не важно что там писать. Пробовал даже делать ссылку на sh скрипт и запускать программу из него, но тоже мимо. Сделал тестовую программу по вашему примеру, она выдает в plainTextEdit следующие ошибки:
ERROR: touch: невозможно выполнить touch для '1'
ERROR: : Отказано в доступе
Process exited with code 1

Comment: запускал из консоли, все норм. отработало

Comment: посмотрите рабочий каталог, из которого touch выполняется (cd вместо touch). Возможно там прав действительно нет

Comment: при запуске с ярлыка linuxdeployqt выдает такую ошибку ERROR: Please ensure that all libraries can be found by ldd. Aborting. То есть, просто тупо не может найти библиотеки.

Comment: смотрите что ldd говорит. каких библиотек не хватает

Comment: Тут прикол в том что ldd, как раз-таки, прекрасно находит эти библиотеки, хотя linuxdeployqt говорит что ldd не может )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58115869/qt-deployment-cant-finde-my-libs-but-ldd-can

Comment: думается что версия установленных в системе библиотек не совпадает с qt под который собирался проект

Comment: Чот я дурень невнимательный, только теперь заметил. Иногда смотрю в книгу и упорно вижу фигу. ldd, запущенный из QProcess, генерирует список недостающих библиотек, но ищет их где-то в  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/, а там их нет.

Answer (score 0):

Так, нагуглил про BASH. В UBUNTU-подобных ОС sudo требует ключа "-S", причем, именно большого "S", иначе не получится:

```
echo MyPassword | sudo -S touch 1
```